# write a function that takes 2 string arguments

Tags: python, string, function, arguments

I'm a total beginner so please skip this one if you are offended by how simple it is.

I can't figure out how to write a function which takes two arguments (name and course) and prints : Welcome "name" to the "course" bootcamp.

```py
def greeting('name', 'course'):
    print (welcome,'name', to, the, 'course')
```

I want to be able to print Welcome Stacie to the python bootcamp!

Comment: Welcome to SO! The variables _contain_ strings, not _are_ strings: remove all your quotes around the variables and put them around the string literals like `"welcome"` and `"to"`, `"the"`.

Answer (score 3):

Pls try something like below.

```
def greeting(name, course):
    print ('welcome' + name + 'to' + 'the' + course)

greeting('Stacie', 'python')
```

if you still getting any error pls share screenshot of error.

Comment: No, don't post screenshots of errors. We want the actual traceback, as text.

Comment: Not "also". Instead.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

```
def greeting(name, course):
    print (f"Welcome {name} to the {course}")

greeting("Jhon", "Python for Beginners")
# > Welcome Jhon to the Python for Beginners
```

The function takes two variables, the variables are not strings, so they won't have quote marks. In the print statement, `f"<text>"` is used in this case to print variables in the string with the help of `{}`. So when you type in the string `{name}` it will take the name from the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

The function arguments you declare need to be *variables*, not actual *values*.

```py
def greeting(name, course):
    print ('welcome', name, 'to the', course)
```

Notice how you had the quoting diametrically wrong. The single quotes go around pieces of human-readable text and the stuff without quotes around it needs to be a valid Python symbol or expression.

If you want to supply a default value, you can do that.

```py
def greeting(name='John', course='Python 101 course'):
    print ('welcome', name, 'to the', course)
```

Calling `greeting()` will produce

```
welcome John to the Python 101 course
```

and of course calling it with arguments like

```
greeting('Slartibartfast', 'Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster course')
```

will fill the variables with the values you passed as arguments:

```
welcome Slartibartfast to the Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster course
```